# Java: Adding new record to database using prepare statement

Tags: java, database

I'm working on a Java project using the NetBeans GUI generator and Derby. I'm having trouble adding a new record to a database table using a button and text field.

The ActionPerformed for the button being used extracts the input from the text field, and sends it to the addCustomer method inside the customer class. Below is the code for the customer class and the addCustomer method. The class also calls a separate class, DBConnection, that establishes a connection to the database.

I'm fairly new to working with databases in Java, so any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Customer extends DBConnection
{
private PreparedStatement insertNewCustomer;
private PreparedStatement allCustomers;

//Customer Class Constructor
public Customer()
{
    getConnection();
    try
    {
        insertNewCustomer = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Customer" + "Name" + "VALUES (?)");
        allCustomers = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Customer");
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlException)
    {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }  
}
//End of constructor

//Adds a new customer to the CUSTOMER table in the database
public void addCustomer(String newName)
{
    try {
        insertNewCustomer.setString(1,newName);
        insertNewCustomer.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqlException) 
    {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the concatenation? You know that's going to end up as `"INSERT INTO CustomerNameVALUES (?)"`

Comment: Also. What is your question?

Comment: Tried to reference an example from the book used for my class. For whatever reason it used that weird concatenation so I just went with it.. I'm basically looking for help to fix this issue so this will successfully add to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert SQL Syntax is incorrect that you have passed to prepareStatement.
It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two ways.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

If you are adding values for all the columns of the table, you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query.

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

I assume Customer is your table name then the correct syntax in your case is

```
 insertNewCustomer = connection.prepareStatement
 ("INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (?)");
```

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't aware of this, very good to know continuing with this project. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's almost always best to list the columns, though, because all sorts of happenings may change the order.

Comment: Please do not rely on the default ordering. Always specify your column orderings. You will save yourself so many small bugs over time, it is well worth the small amount of extra time it takes.